# Login page authentication using slim framework using post method

Tags: php, html, slim

I am new to Slim framework and I would like to pass my code from HTML to another PHP where I have used Slim framework:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>    
<body background="login_bg.jpg">
    <form action="/app/api/login_process.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basicaddon1">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
           Sign In
        </button>
    </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

Here is my login_process code

```
<?php
$app->post('/api/login',function($request)
    {
        require_once('dbconnect.php');
        $lid=$request->getParsedBody()['username'];
        $pwd=$request->getParsedBody()['password'];
        mysql_select_db("slim_db");
        $sql_login="select login_id,pwd from login where login_id=".$lid." and pwd=".$pwd;
        $res_login=mysql_query($sql_login);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res_login))
        {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        if(isset($data))
        {
            header('Content-Type:application/json');
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
);
```

This code works when it is used in get method but leaves me error method not allowed method must be one of post for **POST method**.

I want somebody to guide me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Slim version?

Comment: Check your action attribute on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with route, replace `/app/api/login_process.php` with `/app/api/login`:

```
<form action="/app/api/login" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `app` and `api` are on the same server, and you have the `.htaccess` set properly, the below should solve the problem.

```
<form action="/api/login" method="post">
```

Or if you haven't done the `.htaccess` then this should help:

```
<form action="path_to_api_php" method="post">
```